# Shared instance of c file in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I am working on a chess engine in **C/Objective-C** and I rewrote a large part of my engine in straight-c to improve the speed. My question is, I have about 3KB of tables I initialize in my C file that I don't want to reinitialize every time a function from this file is called. If this were a regular objective-c class I would create a shared instance. However, the core of my engine is in two **.h** and a **.c** files. **Should I make all of the tables used by my engine static? Will they persist between multiple other files calling functions in my engine?** Should I make a static struct to hold my tables? I'm not sure what the best approach is here. Thanks!

Example:

Test.h:

```
int getInt(int index);
```

Test.c:

```
static int integers[4] = {1,2,3,4};
int getInt(int index) { return integers[index]; }
```

Every time I call getInt from another file, will it reallocate 'integers'? Or will it reuse the same array? I want to prevent it from unnecessarily reallocating a bunch of static arrays.

Comment: Why not passing a pointer to your struct as a parameter ? Making it static won't solve your problem as you have multiples files. It should be a global then...

Comment: They already are global. I'm updating my post with an example.

Comment: @Antzi I updated my post with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what you did was accessor on a static variable...

A static is only initialized once, so it does get initialized only once per launch.
You can keep it this way, or change it to a global to access it without calling function.

This code could typically get inlined, so changing it to a global is more a matter of taste than performances.

```
Edit: short summary on allocations

static int array[] = {1, 2}; // Allocated and initialized once
int array2[] = {1, 2, 3}; // Allocated and initialized once

int function() {
 int array3[] = {1, 2, 3}; // Allocated and initialized at every call of function();
 static int *array4 = malloc(42); // Allocated and initialized once
 int *toto = malloc(42); // Allocated at every call of function();
}
```

Comment: The getInt function was just an example. In reality I am working on a chess engine so speed is super important (hence rewriting it in c). I have about 2.5KB in arrays that I am currently allocating with an initialization function. They don't need to be accessed externally - only by functions defined within my .c file. I just want to prevent it from reallocating them every time I call one of the public functions accessible through the .h

Comment: @AttilaTheFun I edited the answer to explain a bit more about allocation, hope this helps. If you return a pointer from your init function, or if you alloc it statically (like in array3), you won't have any double allocation.

Comment: I think I was unclear. The question I'm getting at is, in the example you gave, if function() was prototyped in your header file and I called function from two different other files that include your header, would array and array2 get allocated and initialized once or twice? I am trying to prevent it from reinitializing and reallocating every time I call functions from this file. I would use a shared instance in objective c, but I'm not sure whether the static qualifier will work for that.

Comment: @AttilaTheFun the initialization will happen once, it does not matter how many files are involved. Just make sure not to declare the static inside the .h. Prototyping and declaring extern variables in a .h is fine.